# HTML5 javascript paint brushes

Tags: html, canvas, brush

Hello maybe anyone know where i can found nice and smooth HTML5 brushes like a `http://muro.deviantart.com/` i try to find in but all brushes only in photoshop or desktop applications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because You are asking "how is this done" which is usually off-topic for Stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your link is drawing a smooth line by:

1. Gathering all the raw coordinates coming from mousemove.
2. Applying a line simplification algorithm to remove excess coordinates that cause small unappealing angle bends in the line.

Here's a nice tutorial of line simplification by Mike Bostock (creator of the awesome D3 data visualization library).

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/

Also, here are some nice brush styles created by Kangax (who is also the author of FabricJS--an excellent canvas drawing library):

http://perfectionkills.com/exploring-canvas-drawing-techniques/